# BlackBerry custom image on "mouseOver" menuitem

Tags: blackberry, menuitem

Is it possible to change background of active item in menu? (It's SDK6)

Like in picture:

[image]

And how I can get rid of this (last repeat of background):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that Menu, as an object, is just a customized popupscreen. Maybe extend popupscreen and draw the focus however you'd like it. Submenus will get trickier.